# How to check whether Runnable is attached to view or not

Tags: android, android-activity

I have used Runnable and attached it to view, I am confused that how can i check that whether the same view already have runnable attached or not?
Please see example for more clarification..

```
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myButton.postDelayed(this, 60000);
        // code
    }
};


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myButton.Post(mRunnable); // Here i want to check whether runnable is already added or not
}

 @Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    myButton.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
}
```

Comment: Use boolean flag ...

Answer (score 0):

> // Here i want to check whether runnable is already added or not

There is no way to know it. What you can do is to call

```
myButton.removeCallBacks(null);
```

just before calling `myButton.post(mRunnable);`.

This way, you will be certain that you have only one instance of `mRunnable` queued, when `onResume` is called. In order to avoid leaks, you should clean up the queue `onPause`

Comment: All this is correct, but it's probably not exactly what the OP tries to achieve. In your proposed solution the "60s timer" is reset, whereas if you could do what the OP is looking for, it wouldn't be.

Comment: that's true. But just think what  could happens if he leaves that activity for more than 60secs, without calling  `removeCallBacks(null);`, onPause. @ci_